# From LoginActivity to HomeActivity (Android/Java)

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an activity which makes login through facebook possible. After login i want to load another activity which basically only has a layout. I want to test this process first and if successful continue on. However when i press the  button nothing happens. Any idea what i am doing wrong here? The Activities are also declared in manifest.

This LoginActivity

```
public class LoginActivity  extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    updateImageButton();
}

private void updateImageButton() {
    if(fb.isSessionValid()){

    }else{

    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // callback when session changes state
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                // make request to;2 the /me API
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.
                        GraphUserCallback() {

                    // callback after Graph API response with user object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            //TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                            //welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "welcome", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }

    });
}
}
```

This is HomeActivity

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does onCompleted ever get called?

Comment: An if so is user null?

Comment: No all that is being called is shown above,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `OnClickListener` is not being called appropriate. Try following:

First make following change:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
...
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
button.setOnClickListener(this);
updateImageButton();
...
}
```

Second call onClick like this:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.loginButton:

        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // callback when session changes state
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                // make request to;2 the /me API
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.
                        GraphUserCallback() {

                    // callback after Graph API response with user object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            //TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                            //welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "welcome", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```